# Python Selenium - Use a looping statement to get each website's element attributes from a website list file

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

How can I loop through a list of websites (from an Excel file) to get a value from each website using Python Selenium?

For example, a column in an Excel file contains:

```
https://www.inc.com/profile/dom-&-tom
https://www.inc.com/profile/decksouth
https://www.inc.com/profile/shp-financial
and many more.....
```

I want to get a specific HREF attribue from each link.

My code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.inc.com/profile/bluestone-staffing")
website_link_anchor = 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@class='website']/a")
actual_website_link = website_link_anchor.get_attribute("href")
print(actual_website_link)

browser.get("https://www.inc.com/profile/homecity-real-estate")
website_link_anchor = 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@class='website']/a")
actual_website_link = website_link_anchor.get_attribute("href")
print(actual_website_link)

browser.close()
```

Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the extension of your excel file?

Comment: Hi Nihal, I would like to use the .xlsx format

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a list of websites (from an Excel file) and to get a value from each website you need to:

- Create a *List* of the websites you want to browse.
- Then invoke each website and look out for the desired element.
- Print the actual_website_link and loop again.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Your sample code will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  myLinks = ['https://www.inc.com/profile/dom-&-tom', 'https://www.inc.com/profile/decksouth', 'https://www.inc.com/profile/shp-financial']

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')  
  for link in myLinks:
      browser.get(link)
      website_link_anchor = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@class='website']/a")
      actual_website_link = website_link_anchor.get_attribute("href")
      print(actual_website_link)
  browser.quit()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

to read excel use `xlrd` library. In `sheet.cell_value(i, 0)` here `i` is `row` index and `0` is column index. change column index as per your excel data.

defined function for scrapping and return value or append it to another list if necessary. in your case you are just printing,  so i return `None`

```
import xlrd
from selenium import webdriver
# Give the location of the file


def scrapping(browser, links):

    browser.get(links)
    website_link_anchor = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@class='website']/a")
    actual_website_link = website_link_anchor.get_attribute("href")
    print(actual_website_link)
    return None


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

loc = ("path of file")

# To open Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
# links = []


for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    scrapping(driver, sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    # links.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))

driver.close()
```

Comment: NIhal, I was able to figure it out with xlwt, xlrd, xlutils but I cannot seem to write to an .xlsx file using xlwt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Any suggestions to improve my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy

def scraping(browser, link):
    returnValue = ""
    browser.get(link)
    try:
        website_link_anchor = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@class='website']/a")
        actual_website_link = website_link_anchor.get_attribute("href")
        returnValue = actual_website_link
    except NoSuchElementException: 
        returnValue = "Element not found for: " + link
    return returnValue

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')

file_to_read = ("C:\INC5000\list.xlsx")

# read
file_to_read_wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_to_read)
file_to_read_wb_sheet = file_to_read_wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# copy and write
file_to_write_to_wb = copy(file_to_read_wb)
file_to_write_to_wb_sheet = file_to_write_to_wb.get_sheet(0)

for i in range(1, file_to_read_wb_sheet.nrows):
    result = scraping(browser, file_to_read_wb_sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    file_to_write_to_wb_sheet.write(i, 1, result)

file_to_write_to_wb.save("C:\INC5000\list2.xls")

browser.close()
```